# Org-Mode Agenda Open in Left Window by Default

Tags: org-mode, window, org-agenda, window-splitting

With a vertical split (C-x 3), regardless of which buffer I am in, C-c a opens the agenda on the right window, pushing my org file into the left window.

Is it possible to have the agenda open into the left window, rather than the right? If yes, how?

Comment: You have a few choices:  (1) customize the variable `org-agenda-window-setup` within the recognized available options and just live within those limits; (2) modify the function `org-agenda-prepare-window`, but most people (for whatever the reasons) cringe at the thought of touching a sacred/holy built-in function; (3) add a `display-buffer-alist` entry to try and trump the behavior of `org-switch-to-buffer-other-window` when the aforementioned variable has the value of `'other-window`; (4) there is another variable that is modifiable to affect the display-buffer family of functions, special ..

Comment: Upon further looking into the code, I see that `org-switch-to-buffer-other-window` uses `org-no-popups` and `switch-to-buffer-other-window`.  In the version of `org-mode` that I examined, the `display-buffer-alist` is temporarily let-bound to `nil` by `org-no-popups` -- thus, modifying the `display-buffer-alist` would not work in my case.  `org-no-popus` runs a test to let-bind `pop-up-frames display-buffer-alist` or `pop-up-frames special-display-buffer-names special-display-regexps special-display-function` -- so depending upon the outcome of the test, some of those variables can be used.

Comment: Thanks, lawlist. Very grateful for all your help; I'll be very happy if I have half your skill with this someday. I've saved this info into my org file -- to revisit when I'm a little deeper into emacs . . .

Comment: Is there a chance someone can mold the above stuff into an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I like my Agenda to pop up in the right window, but I made a little modification that makes it pop in the left:

```
(defun my-org-agenda ()
  (interactive)
  (split-window-right)
  (let ((org-agenda-window-setup 'current-window))
    (org-agenda nil "c")))
```

Note that I like to display my custom "c" option by default, but you can remove nil and "c" if you just want the menu.